# c++11 sorting list using lambda

Tags: c++, list, sorting, c++11, lambda

While practicing the use of lambdas, I wrote this program which is supposed to sort a `list` of `pair`s by their second element (an `int`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list<pair <string, int>> s = {{"two", 2}, {"one", 1}, {"three", 3}};

    sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](pair<string,int> a, pair<string, int> b) -> bool {
        return (a.second) > (b.second);
    });

    for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](pair<string, int> a) {
        cout << a.first << " " << a.second << endl;
    });
}
```

I get those errors, though:

```
c:\qt\qt5.2.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5513: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> >' and 'std::_List_iterator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> >')
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2, __comp);
                  ^

c:\qt\qt5.2.0\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2245: ошибка: 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = main()::__lambda0]', declared using local type 'main()::__lambda0', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     __final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
     ^
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may not use `std::sort` with sequential containers such as `std::list` or `std::forward_list` because they have no random access iterator that is required by the standard algorithm `std::sort`. By this reason the both containers have their own member functions sort.

In you case the code will look the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<pair <string, int>> s = {{"two", 2}, {"one", 1}, {"three", 3}};
    s.sort( []( const pair<string,int> &a, const pair<string,int> &b ) { return a.second > b.second; } );

    for ( const auto &p : s )
    {
        cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Take into account that you need to include header `<string>` otherwise your program will not be compiled with other compilers.

Answer (score 13):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires random access iterators, which `std::list` does not have. But you can use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead.

```
s.sort([](const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b)
       {
         return (a.second) > (b.second);
       });
```

where I have made the parameters of the predicate `const` references, since there is no need to copy them, and doing so might incur some unnecessary overhead.