# C++ Sorting Data Type without classes or structs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, file-io, printf

Trying to implement a cpp program that sorts a list of publications according to the year without using a class.

Let's say this information was in a text file, each seperated by a tabspace:

```
save_app    "authors_list3"  "title3"   "conference2"   2010    "oral"
```

And in this function, I have to store this data in a list (preferably with vectors)

```
#include <tuple>
...
void SaveApp(const vector<string>& tokens){

  string authors = tokens[1];
  string title = tokens[2];
  string venue = tokens[3];
  int year = atoi(tokens[4].c_str());
  string presentation = tokens[5];

  vector<tuple<string, string, string, int, string>> line; //I used this because there's no boost function.

}
```

My question is how do I store this data into a vector so that in a later function, I can just sort the entire vector according the the year? Also, I need to iterate to see if there are more than just 1 line of information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++11 sorting list using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281962/c11-sorting-list-using-lambda)

Comment: `vector<tuple<string, string, string, int, string>>` can be sorted according to the int component - done. What's the reason to **not** use a struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `sort(v.begin(),v.end())` is called on `vector< pair< int,tuple< string,string,string,string> > > v` it sorts by the int.